# Laptop fans won't stop running after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, 22.04, fan

Did the upgrade yesterday and my fans just won't stop. This was not happening on Ubuntu 22.04

> Hardware Model: Dell Inc. Precision 3560
> Firmware version: 1.26.2
> Memory: 16.0 GiB
> Processor: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 × 8
> Graphics: NVIDIA T500 / Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
> Disk Capacity: 512.1 GB  OS Name: Ubuntu 23.04  OS Type: 64-bit  GNOME
> Version: 44.3  Windowing System: X11  Kernel version: Linux
> 6.2.0-35-generic

Edit: When I say upgrading from 22.04 to 23.04, I actually meant I installed 23.04 on my laptop that already had 22.04 on it.

Comment: Upgrading directly from 22.04 to 23.04 is not supported ... how did you you upgrade ?

Comment: Sorry, I actually overwrote 23.04 ontop of 22.04 (a clean install from scratch). I will edit the description